# How to remove axis labels in FactoMineR of R?

Tags: r, label, axis

How to remove the axis label, axis ticks and title in the FactoMineR package of R? The following code gives an error saying "formal argument "xlab" matched by multiple actual arguments":

```
require(FactoMineR)
plot(res.pca,choix="var", shadow=TRUE,
     select = c("Tree", "Fish"),
     yaxt="n", xaxt="n", xlab="", ylab="", col.var = "red", cex=2, lwd=2, title=NA)
```

If I get rid of xlab="", ylab="", things work fine except for the fact that I have the x and y axis labels. I don't want those.

Comment: wow that is an annoying package name. What kind of object are you plotting?

Comment: > class(res.pca)
[1] "PCA"   "list ". List I guess!!

Answer (score 1):

```
plot(..., col.lab="white")
```

And then

```
mtext('My_X_Label', side=1, line=3)
mtext('My_Y_Label', side=2, line=3)
```

if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Hye,
I think you have to set the option "graph =FALSE " when you conduct the PCA:

`PCA((res.pca,graph=FALSE)`

Then you can plot with options
cat